# Read list of blobs where urls are in a data frame

Tags: azure, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I have a list of blobs (wasbs url) in a structured streaming data frame and want to read all the blob contents into another data frame. 
Spark.read.text(list of files) does not accept data frame as a parameter. 
How do I get the data

Comment: Just making sure I got this right?; you have a list of URLs from which you want to create a single DF out of?

Are these URLs pointing to which file format files? Is the schema same for all these files?

Comment: have you tried doing `Spark.read.text(df.collect())` , assuming dataframe containing wasb urls is small enough so you can issue `.collect()` on it which returns list of urls